# What Js is deploying inline style to Submenu/Top navigation

Tags: magento2, topmenu

I made some changes to a Top navigation (changing ul.submenu to div.submenu), all is fine, but I cannot find where in a Js is setup this inline style:

```
style="display: none; top: 53px; left: -0.453125px;"
```

It is part of this code:

```
<ul class="level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none; top: 53px; left: -0.453125px;" aria-hidden="true">
```

I tried to find it in

`magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/js/navigation-menu.js`

but no luck.

I want to change this so that:

```
left: 0;
width: <calculate based on a platform used>;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The menu is a jQuery UI element.

You can edit its settings by extending the following file in your theme: Magento_Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
it says:

```
<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The menu settings are:

```
data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'
```

For instance, you can change the positions of the submenus by changing the values in data-mage-init according the documentation in jQuery UI, for example .position:
https://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Would you please be kind and explain what (position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}) means and how it works?